# Ubuntu 18 Tmux 2.6-3 copy paste functionality with xclip non functional

Tags: command-line, terminal, tmux, clipboard

I recently did a fresh Ubuntu 18 install and copied over my home directory from my previous Ubuntu 16 setup. However this seems to have broken the copy paste functionality I had previously with xclip (0.12 installed).

My previous tmux.conf method:

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind -t vi-copy y copy-pipe "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

I've looked at other similar questions on here but unfortunately none of them match my exact scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of tmux 2.6, `bind-key` no longer takes a mode-table option (`-t`).  Instead, there is a a key-table (`-T`) for each mode.

Additionally, commands can't be used directly in copy-mode bindings.  They have to be sent with `send-keys -X`.

From [comments on tmux issue 754](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/754#issuecomment-297452143):

> 1. replace `-t` with `-T`
> 2. replace `vi-<name>` with `<name>-mode-vi`
> 3. prefix the command with `send-keys -X`

Furthermore, from version 2.4 onwards, the new command `copy-pipe-and-cancel` leaves copy mode, while `copy-pipe` keeps it active.

So that line in your `tmux.conf` becomes:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "xclip -sel clip -i"
```

### Garbage printed to the screen

Depending on your terminal emulator, you may also see some characters dumped to the screen after using this binding.  This is down to the [`set-clipboard` feature](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#set-clipboard):

> Attempt to set the terminal clipboard content using the xterm(1) escape sequence, if there is an *Ms* entry in the terminfo(5) description (see the TERMINFO EXTENSIONS section).

It appears that some terminals (such as LXTerminal) will set TERM to `xterm` (which supports this extension), but don't actually recognise the sequence.  `copy-pipe` and `copy-pipe-and-cancel` will "helpfully" attempt to use this feature, and the terminal simply displays the resulting characters.  What you're seeing is the escape sequence followed by the base64-encoding of the selected text.

If your terminal is one that mishandles this escape sequence, you can disable it with

```
set-option -g set-clipboard off
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but still no luck. When I select the area pressing 'y' has no affect where it should instead copy the selected area

Comment: Have you restarted all `tmux` sessions after changing this line?  Are there any error messages, either when `tmux` starts (and reads this line from the config file) or when you use the binding?

Comment: All tmux sessions? No I just tested in a new one. I'll restart all of them and give it another try when I'm back at work on monday. Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry I've been so long, Christmas holidays and all. It kind of works now, I can copy things, but when I press 'y' as well as copying it also sticks a bunch of characters on the screen, the first is weird utf8 and the rest are ascii but jumbled. I'll make as accepted though since it is usable.

Comment: @Shard Which terminal are you using?  I see that exact symptom in LXTerm, but not in any others.  I haven't got to the bottom of it yet, although I noticed that the characters are the base64-encoding of the copied text.

Comment: Just using the gnome terminal which is default with ubuntu 18 @JigglyNaga

Comment: Does adding `set-option -g set-clipboard off` stop the extra characters from appearing?

Comment: It does, but then when I press y it doesn't go back into normal mode, it stays in copy mode selected so I have to exit that by pressing ctrl-c or enter