# Run command in copy mode

Tags: tmux

For my current project, most work happens in tmux on a remote system. Sometimes, I would like to copy text from the remote system to my local machine (i.e. for sending email). My current workflow is

- Enter tmux copy mode and copy text
- Run `:save-buffer ~/clipboard` in tmux
- On my local machine, I have a command aliased to `ssh remote-machine 'cat ~/clipboard' | pbcopy`

This is a huge pain, and I'm wondering if there's a way to run a script in copy mode. Specifically, is there a way I can bind the command `:save-buffer ~/clipboard` to pressing Enter in copy mode? (or maybe on buffer update?)

The machine I am ssh'ing into the remote machine from is not constant, so it's ok if I still have to run the command on my mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in copy-mode, you can use [`copy-pipe <command>`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#copy-pipe__command_), with a command such as `cat > ~/clipboard`.

In Tmux 2.5 or later, you can bind that to Enter with

```
bind-key -T copy-mode Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe "cat > ~/clipboard"
```

(or `-T copy-mode-vi`, depending on your `mode-keys` setting)

See also: [copy paste functionality with xclip non functional](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484899/90751)